# How to compile dynamic library for a JNI application on linux?

Tags: java, c++, linux, java-native-interface, compilation

I'm using **Ubuntu 10.10**

So that's what I did.

*Hello.java*:

```
class Hello {
        public native void sayHello();

        static { System.loadLibrary("hellolib"); }

        public static void main(String[] args){
                Hello h = new Hello();
                h.sayHello();
        }
}
```

Then I ran the follwing commands:

```
dierre@cox:~/Scrivania/provajni$ javac Hello.java

dierre@cox:~/Scrivania/provajni$ javah -jni Hello
```

I've obtained `Hello.class` and `Hello.h`.

*Hello.h*:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Hello */

#ifndef _Included_Hello
#define _Included_Hello
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Hello
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Then I created *Hello.cpp*:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Hello.h"
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
        return;
}
```

And now the part where I think I screwed up. I was *inspired* by this [guide (*Compile the Dynamic or Shared Object Library* section)](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html):

```
dierre@cox:~/Scrivania/provajni$ gcc -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux" -o hellolib.so -shared -Wl,-soname,hello.so Hello.cpp -static -lc
```

that generates the file `hellolib.so`

But when I try to run it with `java Hello` I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hellolib in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
 at Hello.<clinit>(Hello.java:4)
Could not find the main class: Hello.  Program will exit.
```

I even tried this:

```
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

with no results.

I know I'm doing something extremely stupid but I can't figure out what it is. The dynamic lib is generated with the -shared option, isn't it?

**Update #1**

I tried `static { System.load("/home/dierre/Scrivania/provajni/hellolib.so"); }` to see if that worked but now:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/dierre/Scrivania/provajni/hello.so: /home/dierre/Scrivania/provajni/hello.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt4cout
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1803)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1699)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
    at Hello.<clinit>(Hello.java:4)
```

**Update #2**
Ok, to solve the *Update #1* problem I had to use `g++` insted of `gcc`, obviously. Still having trouble to use the `load` method though. I can't seem to tell it the right path.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Native library can be loaded by loadLibrary with a valid name. By example, lib**XXXX**.so for linux family, your hellolib.so should rename to libhello.so. 
By the way, I develop java with jni, I will separate the implementation and native interface (.c or .cpp).

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello"); // will load libhello.so
}
```

The implementation header(HelloImpl.h):

```
#ifndef _HELLO_IMPL_H
#define _HELLO_IMPL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
#endif

        void sayHello ();

#ifdef __cplusplus
        }
#endif

#endif
```

HelloImpl.cpp:

```
#include "HelloImpl.h"
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sayHello () {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Hello.c (I prefer to compile jni in c):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Hello.h"
#include "HelloImpl.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    sayHello();
    return;
}
```

Finally, we can compile them in some steps:

1. compile obj (generate HelloImpl.o)

> g++ -c -I"/opt/java/include"
>   -I"/opt/java/include/linux" HelloImpl.cpp

2. compile jni with .o

> g++ -I"/opt/java/include"
>   -I"/opt/java/include/linux" -o libhello.so -shared
>   -Wl,-soname,hello.so Hello.c HelloImpl.o -static -lc

in step 2, we use g++ to compile it. This is very important. yor can see [How to mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)

After compilation, you can check the function naming with nm:

```
$ nm libhello.so |grep say
00000708 T Java_Hello_sayHello
00000784 t _GLOBAL__I_sayHello
00000718 T sayHello
```

There is a Java_Hello_sayHello marked T. It should extactly equal to your native method name. If everything is ok. you can run it:

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=. Hello
Hello World!
```

Comment: This works for me, if I leave out the "-static" option in the last compilation step. If I don't, I get this error: 

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__DTOR_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I found the solution in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634387/c-statically-linked-shared-library

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can u please explain what is this -Djava.library.path=. Hello

Comment: -Djava.library.path=. specifies where java should look for libXXX.so files (. means the current directory)

Answer (score 33):

Finally my code works.
This is hello.java

```
public class hello {
  public native void sayHello(int length) ;
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    String str = "I am a good boy" ;
    hello h = new hello () ;
    h.sayHello (str.length() ) ;
  }
  static {
    System.loadLibrary ( "hello" ) ;
  }
}
```

You should compile it as :

```
$ javac hello.java
```

To create .h file you should run this command:

```
$ javah -jni hello
```

This is `hello.h`:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_hello_sayHello
(JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);
```

Here is `hello.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>
#include "hello.h" 

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_hello_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jint len) {
  printf ( "\nLength is %d", len ); }
```

To compile this and to create a shared library we have to run this command :

```
$ gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -o libhello.so -shared hello.c
```

Then finally run this one :

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=. hello
```

Comment: when I compile, it works when I do: `gcc -I/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_91/include  /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_91/include/linux -o libhello.so -shared -fPIC hello.c`

Comment: @tidy Your command line worked for me, otherwise Sandipan's example is good.

Answer (score 5):

This complains about the C++ symbols not being available. I seem to remember, when I use to do JNI stuff all of the time that there were problems linking in C++ libraries and we always stuck to plain old C

If you change your code so that it's standard C (and rename the file):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Hello.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        printf("Hello World");
        return;
}
```

And compile it

```
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include  -o libhellolib.so -shared Hello.c
```

It works

```
java -Djava.library.path=`pwd` Hello
Hello World
```

Comment: dierre@cox:~/Scrivania/provajni$ ldd hello.so 
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00b46000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0018d000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00b16000)

Comment: it was gcc instead of g++. But I still can't use `loadLibrary`, only `load`