# C++ Statically linked shared library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, crt, dynamic-library

I have a shared library used by a another application beyond my control which requires *.so objects. My library makes use of sqlite3 which needs to be statically linked with it (I absolutely need a self-contained binary).

When I try to compile and link my library:

```
-fpic -flto -pthread -m64
-flto -static -shared
```

I end up with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__DTOR_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtbeginT.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is *recompile with -fPIC* related to? My code or CRT?

I have already tried to compile my object with -fPIC with the same result.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The problem does not seem to be related to SQLite3.

I wrote a simple one-line-do-nothing library which compiles and links like this:

```
g++ -c -fPIC -o bar.o bar.cpp
g++ -shared -o bar.so bar.o
```

but not like this:

```
g++ -c -fPIC -o bar.o bar.cpp
g++ -static -shared -o bar.so bar.o
```

The problem seems to be related to CRT (crtbeginT.o). Am I supposed to recompile GCC --with-pic or anything?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Are you trying to just link your library to a static sqlite library, or are you trying to do something else as well ?

Comment: PIC = Position Independent Code, required for shared libs (on most architectures, I guess)

Comment: @nos Trying to link my shared library with sqlite3.a

Comment: @Petr In that case you should at least drop the `-static` flag, and if you have a shared lib version of sqlite as well, use `-Wl,-Bstatic -lsqlite3 -Wl,-Bdynamic` to make it pick up the static version of libsqlite.

Comment: @nos Thanks. -Bstatic seems to work. Don't really know why as it is supposed to be the same as -static (at least according to the manual). If you want you can write an answer so I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `-static` flag when creating a shared library, it's for creating statically linked executables.

If you only have a static version of the library, you can just link it in using `-lsqlite3`. But if there's both a dynamic version(.so) and a static version, the linker will prefer the dynamic one.

To instruct the linker to pick the static one, give the linker the `-Bstatic` flag, and make it switch back to dynamic linking for other stuff (like libc and dynamic runtime support) with `-Bdynamic`. That is, you use the flags:

```
 -Wl,-Bstatic -lsqlite3 -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Alternativly, you can just specify the full path of the .a file, e.g. `/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a` instead of any compiler/linker flags.

With the GNU ld, you can also use `-l:libsqlite3.a` instead of `-lsqlite3`. This will force the use of the library file `libsqlite3.a` instead of `libsqlite3.so`, which the linker prefers by default.

Remember to make sure the .a file have been compiled with the `-fpic` flag, otherwise you normally can't embed it in a shared library.

Comment: I've have same problem here and don't know how to compile shared library that DOES NOT dynamically links to distribution dependent staff like libc/libstdc++ - `-Bstatic` do provide dynamically linked shared library. Wonderfully, using MinGW on Windows I can link .dll with `-static` properly (depending only on windows dlls but not mingw's one). Is there a way to link .so statically???

Comment: No. unix shared libraries work very differently from windows dlls.

Comment: The -l:libsqlite3.a trick works in eclipse cdt as well. Enter :libsqlite3.a in Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C Linker->Libraries and the build will statically link against the library.

Comment: The full path usually gets the trick done without any mumbo jumbo on which older versions of `ld` seem to fail consistently. Despite pointing it with `-L` to the right folder and using `-Bstatic -lname -Bdynamic`  on the linker command line, I could not get it to work with an ancient `ld` on FreeBSD 8.4. Full path always works, however.

Answer (score 8):

Any code that will somehow make its way into a dynamic library should be relocatable. It means that everything that is linked with your .so, no matter statically or dynamically, should be compiled with `-fPIC`. Specifically, static `sqlite` library should also be compiled with `-fPIC`.

Details of what PIC means are here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code

Comment: Post the complete link commands that you perform so we could analyse further)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently -static is not the same as -Bstatic. I switched to -Bstatic and everything worked.