# Statically linking libc into my binary causes it to segfault

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, libc

I need to build a binary with libc statically linked. I have libc.a available in the same directory as the source code. To compile, I tried the following:

```
gcc -o foo foo.c libc.a
```

This resulted in the following issue:

```
/usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in `libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable
```

In researching this, I found the following question: [Linking partially static and partially dynamic in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161332/linking-partially-static-and-partially-dynamic-in-gcc)

Following the solution in the top answer, I created my own string comparison function in `my_strcmp.c` and tried the following compilation:

```
gcc -o foo foo.c mystrcmp.c libc.a
```

And it works, *but* the binary now segfaults quite early. This doesn't happen without libc statically linked. Here's the GDB trace:

```
(gdb) backtrace                                
#0  0x00000000004fe48e in generic_start_main ()
#1  0x00000000004fe891 in __libc_start_main () 
#2  0x0000000000406b56 in _start ()
```

Not really sure how to interpret this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? If you want a static-linked binary why aren't you using `-static`?

Comment: @R.. I need this binary to be portable to another system running an older glibc version (glibc cannot be upgraded on this system, and the binary cannot be compiled on this system. This is quite a niche problem). I'm not sure how to use `-static`, but I am assuming that my method achieves the same thing, no?

Comment: No, it doesn't achieve the same thing.

Comment: One thing to try, perhaps, is to run `gcc` with the `-static` parameter along with `-v` so you can see what GNU would be doing to build this so you could tailor the command for your unique situation.

Comment: Where this `libc.a` came from?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to produce a static-linked binary, just add `-static` to the command line. You do not need `libc.a` there at all. What you're doing, adding `libc.a` without `-static`, produces a dynamic-linked binary, but pulls in some functions/files (whatever you reference, and everything those reference, recursively) from `libc.a`, and still also has the shared `libc.so` participating in your program. These are not generally able to work together.