# Android ndk and dynamic load library with dlopen

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

i want to load shared library dynamically from external files directory.

I create library and test it on linux, it works. 
Compile: gcc -fPIC -shared -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc test_lib.cpp constructor.cpp -o test.so

But when i use this in android ndk, i get runtime error: 
dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found.

How i can solve it? I'm use emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use libraries built for normal linux on android - it's still linking to the shared `libc.so.6` which isn't available on Android. (You can't statically link a shared library, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637842/3115956.)

You need to build the library using the NDK compiler against the Android C runtime library.

If you're adventurous, you could try forcing it to link the C runtime statically into your library though, by making it link `libc.a` instead of `libc.so`, but I'm not sure if this causes other issues. (One can run executables built for normal linux on android, assuming they're built with `-static`, but I'm not sure how well that works for shared libraries.)

Comment: The first part of your answer is good, but I see no reason to force linking the Android C runtime. That is bad advice when it is easier and safer to actually compile the library for the platform you are targeting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - ideally he should be building his library for the platform he's targeting - I agree. When wanting to run it on android, that would be done by using the android NDK, which would make sure it's linked against the android C runtime and not against glibc.

Comment: "You can't use libraries built for normal linux on android - it's still linking to the shared libc.so.6 which isn't available on Android." But for example boost works in ndk. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure about boost, either you're referring to parts of it that only use headers, not a precompiled .so, or that .so doesn't link to anything in glibc?