# Dynamically load shared library from sd card

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I want to dynamically load library from SD card, with dlopen, but when I do it, get error:
dlopen failed: couldn't map "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Tests/armeabi-v7a/libtest.so" segment 2: Operation not permitted

When i use it for internal storage it's work.
What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ndk and dynamic load library with dlopen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592218/android-ndk-and-dynamic-load-library-with-dlopen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is disallowed by Android's security policy. Anyone can write to that location, so loading code from it is an easily exploitable attack vector.

Comment: Thanks. But if copy from sd card location to internal location it's work

Comment: To a controlled location though, right? If you're on a rooted device then lots of the security restrictions are going to be pretty much neutered...