# How to add .so file to the java.library.path in Linux

Tags: linux, java.library.path

I am working with a java application which needs a `.dll` file in java.library.path in windows. To run same application in Linux I have the respective `.so` file which should be added to `java.library.path` in linux machine, I didnt find any easy solution for this so far

I did put the `.so` in a folder which is already in the class path, but my application still complains there is no required `.so` file in `java.library.path`

I'd like to find:

1. Ways to add `.so` to `java.library.path`
2. How to know if its already added (when added)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Add the containing directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before launching the application

```
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/pathOfContainingDirectory
```

Use `java -XshowSettings:properties` to show the java.library.path (and others) value.

Comment: Thanks Jose, this helped me.
I even found other important things with this `java.library.path`
This path is lost after restarting the system, so I add it through /etc/profile file so that It automatically adds when the system restarts,
even the `CLASSPATH` having related .jar files using these `java.library.path` .so files is overwritten by my application initiation's/catalina.sh's CLASSPATH, thus my application was complaining about the .jars and related .so's.
Problem is fixed once `ClASSPATH` has the required .jar file and also the required .so file in the `java.library.path`.

Comment: For the confused runners of `java -XshowSettings:properties`. My version of java prints out the properties, and then prints out `--help`. So I need to scroll up to see the settings.

Comment: Important note is to not have spaces for 'equal'-sign. Novice users may copy the command straight off and wonder why they get a "not a valid identifier" error.

Answer (score 9):

I had a lot of trouble figuring this out, please make sure that you have `lib` prefix in the library name.

So steps,

1. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/pathOfContainingDirectory"`
2. Rename libraries to have lib as a prefix. [Add this as part of build script]

   ```
   mv JNIDemo.so libJNIDemo.so
   ```

Check this answer for detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987567/2076566

Answer (score 3):

I used java -XshowSettings:properties method and found the path of a previously set folder and copied my so file to that folder

Comment: Hi @Ravindu I tried your approach. Its not working for me. I changed th permissions to 777 just to be sure.  But nothing happens any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be a better way to do it as it only needs one single link to be created, no file edits needed, no exports or running of source before an application is run. And no bashrc lines needed.

That said, if you upgrade it may cause unintentional errors to future java releases as it might load an outdated library, although one link removal also solves this.

This works under ubuntu 18.04 with java 11 opensdk installed.

```
$ locate libjawt.so
$ java -XshowSettings:properties
```

From the two commands above, you can find the two paths you need to adjust this to your own system.

```
sudo ln -s /path/from/locate/libjawt.so /path/from/properties/libawt.so
```

I made a symlink for java ll open sdk to find the library and mine was as follows because /usr/lib is one of the paths in the output. There is (in my output) a java path you may choose to use instead of /usr/lib if you want to keep java library (even symlinks) together.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjawt.so /usr/lib/libjawt.so
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = null;
private String[] libs_path = System.getProperty("java.library.path").split(":");
public boolean isInstalled() {
    boolean isInstalled = false;
    for(String lib : libs_path) {
            file = new File(lib+"/"+"yourlib.so");
            if(file.exists()) {
                isInstalled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    return isInstalled;
}


public void install() {
    if(!isInstalled) {
        for(String lib: lib_path) {
             // copy your .so to lib
             break;
        }
    }
}
```