# Run opencv program through command line in ubuntu

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu, jar, executable-jar

I have written a Java program for image detection using OpenCV. 
In Eclipse that program is running fine because as I've installed OpenCV to local system and added the jar location to the build path. 
But when I created a project jar and tried to execute it, it showed this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path
```

What should I change to execute the jar through command line for opencv usage?

Comment: You need to configure the path to the opencv_java shared library.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227045/how-to-add-so-file-to-the-java-library-path-in-linux.

Comment: Improved formatting, more tags

Comment: I have already tried   LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/pathOfContainingDirectory