# JNI - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, ubuntu-12.04

I understand this question has been asked many times, I have read many post without positive outcome, thus seeking assistance.

Original source is [Java Programming with JNI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section2.html)

I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libSample1 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
at Sample1.main(Sample1.java:10)
```

Source code is as follows

Sample1.java

```
public class Sample1
{
public native int intMethod(int n);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.loadLibrary("libSample1");
    Sample1 sample  = new Sample1();
    int     square  = sample.intMethod(5);

    System.out.println("intMethod " + square);
}
 }
```

Sample1.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Sample1 */
#ifndef _Included_Sample1
#define _Included_Sample1
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Sample1_intMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Sample1.cpp

```
#include "Sample1.h"
#include <string.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Sample1_intMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint num)
{
return num * num ;
}
```

**OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

Compile command

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/include/linux Sample1.cpp -o libSample1.so
```

I also have tried

```
java -Djava.library.path=/home/userid/java_proj/example Sample1
```

Thank you for the help in advance

**Update -> Answer:** Javah -jni Sample1 fixed the problem

Thanks

Comment: How does this relate to Android? Is the `.so` file executable?

Comment: did you look at [this][1]? I think this addresses your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950635/how-to-compile-dynamic-library-for-a-jni-application-on-linux?rq=1