# how to fix fatal error jvmti.h No such file or directory compilation terminated c code ubuntu?

Tags: java, c, ubuntu, gcc, jvmti

how to fix fatal error jvmti.h No such file or directory compilation terminated c code ubuntu? my c code is:

## include "jvmti.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, char *options, void *reserved)
{

/* We return JNI_OK to signify success */
printf("\nmy name is,\n\n");

return JNI_OK;

}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Agent_OnUnload(JavaVM *vm)
{
}

type this command in terminal: gcc -Wall -W -Werror first_agent.c -o firstagent

first_agent.c:1:19: fatal error: jvmti.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

where java jdk version
javac 1.7.0_25

where gcc version gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu4)

here should update gcc version to 4.8?

Answer (score 5):

This question is now pretty old, but probably someone will stumble across this in the future.

As @Gyro Gearless already mentioned, you need to specify the "Include directories".

For Java 8 on Ubuntu 15.04 I found the folders at

- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include
- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include/linux

In this directories you can find the following header files:

- classfile_constants.h
- jawt.h
- jdwpTransport.h
- jni.h
- jvmticmlr.h
- jvmti.h

which are needed by the compiler to include.

If you are using Netbeans you can add those include directory via the properties of your project:
[image: Right-click on you Project and select "Properties"]

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell gcc where it can find its include files using `-I` option. Here is a sample invocation for building a JNI library. Note this was automatically created from some Maven plugin on Windows, so it is a bit noisy:

```
g++ -m64 -shared -IC:\work\Produktiv\jdpapi\jdpapi-native\src\main\native 
 -IC:\work\Produktiv\jdpapi\jdpapi-native\target\native\javah 
 -IC:\opt\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\..\include 
 -IC:\opt\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\..\include\win32 
 -o C:\work\Produktiv\jdpapi\jdpapi-native\target\objs\DPAPI.obj 
 -c C:\work\Produktiv\jdpapi\jdpapi-native\src\main\native\DPAPI.cpp
```

Note this is really just one line; and of course you have to adjust the paths for Linux :-)

Comment: thanks Gyro Gearless but i don't understand...
iam using ubuntu 13.04 not windows...

Comment: gcc behaves similar on Linux and Windows. Unfortunately, i have no Linux box in reach, but maybe you may find some better examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950635/how-to-compile-dynamic-library-for-a-jni-application-on-linux/3950649#3950649