# JNI HelloWorld compiles, can't find or load main

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to learn how to use JNI and I'm using the code from this thread [How to compile dynamic library for a JNI application on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950635/how-to-compile-dynamic-library-for-a-jni-application-on-linux)

HelloJNI.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "HelloJNImpl.h"
#include "HelloJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    sayHello();
    return;
}
```

HelloJNI.h:

```
#ifndef HELLOJNI_H_
#define HELLOJNI_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#endif

#endif
```

HelloJNImpl.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void sayHello () {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return;
}
```

HelloJNImpl.h

```
#ifndef HELLOJNIMPL_H_
#define HELLOJNIMPL_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
#endif
        void sayHello();

#ifdef __cplusplus
        }

#endif

#endif
```

Next, I've compiled my SO using

```
g++ -I/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_51/include -I/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_51/include/linux -fPIC -o libHelloJNI.so -shared HelloJNI.cpp
```

Which gives me the libHelloJNI.so

I also get the expect results when I use nm

```
nm libHelloJNI.so | grep say
0000000000000675 T Java_Hello_sayHello
                 U sayHello
```

But when I go to test this from my terminal using

```
java -Djava.library.path=. sayHello
Error: Could not find or load main class sayHello
```

It say's that it can't find sayHello.  I think I'm missing something small here and can't find it.  Can someone tell me where I might be going wrong with this code?

Comment: The only difference I can find is in the output of nm from the linked post vs is mine.  In the other post sayHello is marked as T where mine is marked as U